# How do i implement Clean URLs in struts

Tags: java, url, url-rewriting, struts, clean-urls

How do i get rid of .do and query string paths in urls of my application? Idea is to make site more SEO and user friendly.

I would like to make this path:

```
http://something.com/myaction.do?id=1&ground=B
```

into:

```
http://something.com/myaction/1/B
```

Any idea how do i get start? Thanks

Comment: I have only used struts2. In that you can do it by overriding the struts.action.extension constant in the struts.xml file. So may be there's a similar one in struts as well.

Answer (score 1):

It can be implemented by "URL rewriting", which can make your URL more friendly.

You can take a look at [Tuckey urlrewrite](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite),  a Java web filter to rewrite URL.

Answer (score 1):

we can achieved this in Struts by modifying Web.xml and struts-config.xml files.

The following link can help you in implementing this:

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/implementing-clean-url-in-struts/